# after post on wordpress commit to facebook and twitter

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter, social-networking, google-plus

Premise:

I have a blog

I have a page on:

- lookbook
- bloglovin
- facebook
- twitter
- googleplus

Is there any way to send my new blog posts automatically on my social networking page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plugins for facebook and twitter, some are more complicated than others to get going but they work, I've used these ones in the past

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-to-twitter/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-to-facebook/

I'm not too sure on the others though

Comment: You can even set your facebook to take the feed from facebook, so you could actually just post it to twitter and let facebook feed from twitter

Comment: I've not come across one for Google plus, as for the others I haven't really used them so wouldn't be able to help you myself.